# extract the count of fields for a month in a year and export it in json for d3.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, d3.js, line

I have a database in the below format

```
reqested_by | request_date
jack |2014-04-13
john |2014-04-12
james|2014-07-01
```

I want to extract the number of requests in a month. for eg in the above eg. 2 requests in april 2014
and 1 request in july 2014.
this should be exported in a json format to be displayed as a chart in d3.js showing the number of requests per month
I tried extracting the month with its count but not the year

```
$myquery = " select count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=1 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) January, 
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=2 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) February,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=3 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) March,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=4 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) April,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=5 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) May,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=6 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) June,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=7 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) July,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=8 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) August,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=9 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) September,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=10 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) October,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=11 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) November,
                        count(CASE WHEN month(request_date)=12 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) December from request";
    $query = mysqli_query($server,$myquery);

    if ( ! $query ) {
        echo mysqli_error();
        die;
    }

    $data = array();
    $len=mysqli_num_rows($query);
    for ($x = 0; $x < mysqli_num_rows($query); $x++) {
        $data[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query);

    }

    echo json_encode($data);
```

the output is

```
[{"January":"0","February":"0","March":"0","April":"18","May":"2","June":"0","July":"0","August":"0","September":"0","October":"0","November":"0","December":"0"}]
```

but i cant plot line chart based on this value. so i extracted the date as it is and counted it in d3 for the months but wasnt able to display the month on the x axis based on the inputs.
what method should i follow to display the number of counts based on the months on a line chart in d3.js by extracting data through mysql

Comment: It would be trivial to build the json in php from a simple, ordered, result set

Answer (score 0):

The data returned from your server is of the form:

```
[{"January":"0","February":"0","March":"0","April":"18",
  "May":"2","June":"0","July":"0","August":"0",
  "September":"0","October":"0","November":"0","December":"0"}]
```

I assume that when you say you want to create a d3 line chart from that data, you mean that you want the month names to be on the x-axis and the counts to be on the y-axis.

The d3 line charting (and most other) methods expect data to be in an array form, with each element of the array representing a single data point, with the same key structure.  Some possible data structures that would work for d3 are

- Each data point in the array as a sub array, with x and y values determined by position

  ```
  [ ["January", "0"], ["February", "0"], ... ["December", "0"] ]
  ```
- Each data point in the array as an object with the same property names for x and y values

  ```
  [ {x:"January", y:"0"}, {y:"0", x:"February"}, ... {x:"December", y:"0"} ]
  ```

How do you get from your data structure to one of these?  The easiest approach is to use the [`d3.entries(object)` utility function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#d3_entries).  This method (part of the d3 core library) takes a single Javascript object and creates an array representing each property of that object.  Each properties is converted into its own object of the structure `{key:propertyName, value:propertyValue}`.

Therefore, the result of running `var dataArray = d3.entries(dataset)` for the dataset returned by your query would be

```
[ {key:"January", value:"0"}, {key:"February", value:"0"}, 
  ... {key:"December", value:"0"} ]
```

From there you can use d3 code similar to most examples for line charts (like [this one](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245)).